# SQL Server trigger multiple update rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am using a trigger on my table for update.

When I was updating 1 row, it works. But when I update 20 rows at once, the log only show 1 history update.

I want to show all updated rows. How to make it?

This my simple sql:

```
create trigger Triger_Update_Product
on product 
for update
as begin
    declare @first char(10)
    declare @after char(10)

    select @first = name from deleted

    select @after = name from inserted

    insert into historyproduk
        select @first, @after, getdate()
end
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190752.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the trigger in a **set-based** fashion and be aware that `inserted` and `deleted` will contain **multiple rows** - so these lines of code are really bad:

```
select @first = name from deleted
select @after = name from inserted
```

These select **one arbitrary row** from the update set - and they ignore all other rows. **Don't do this!!**

Try this instead:

```
create trigger Trigger_Update_Product
on product 
for update
as begin
    insert into historyproduk
        select d.name, i.name, getdate()
        from deleted d
        inner join inserted i on d.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey
end
```

You need to **join** the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables on the primary key and then grab the `Name` from the old (`deleted`) and new (`Inserted`) and insert those - along with the date/time stamp - into the history table in a single `INSERT ... SELECT ....` statement to handle **multiple rows** being updated